# Javascript using a string variable in Underscore.js .map()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm not even sure how to title this, so apologies up front.

I am using Underscore.js to do the following (create subtotals and spit out the updated array) this works as the values in the return are valid.

```
       var result = _.chain(data)
                      .groupBy("LDC_LoadPro")
                      .map(function (value, key) {
                          return {
                              LDC_LoadPro: value[0].LDC_LoadPro,
                              chr_amount: sum(_.pluck(value, "chr_amount")),
                              cmt_name :'Total'
                          }
                      })
                      .value();

        var copyData = data;

        copyData.push(result);
```

Next when a user wants to sort the data, I need to recalculate the subtotals based on the column they sort. Currently I'm passing the 'columnName' and all is working until I get to the underscore.js .map() and I want to use the columnName variable in the subtotal object. Is there some way to achieve this or should I rethink the process?

```
       var result = _.chain(notSubtotalRecords)
               .groupBy(columnName)
               .map(function (value, key) {
                   return {
                       columnName: value[0].columnName,
                       chr_amount: sum(_.pluck(value, "chr_amount")),
                       cmt_name: 'Total'
                   }
               })
               .value();
      console.log(result);

      notSubtotalRecords.push(result);
```

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but you may be looking for `value[0][columnName]` to use the "columnName" variable's value as a property selector.

Comment: Yea sorry for this being a disaster. What I'm doing is on the click event of the table header I pass a string containing the key of the array. Then I set that to var columnName and want to use it in the .map()

Comment: Well there's nothing stopping you from using the variable in the `.map()` callback. What's not clear is what you need to do with it. What do those `value` components look like? Your code says `value[0]`; is it an array? What's in the array?

Comment: I've added a picture to the post. In the highlighted line, you'll see the commented out line   'LDC_LoadPro: value[0].LDC_LoadPro.  What I want is to use the var columnName (string) but it returns undefined in the result.

Comment: Ah OK, I see what you mean. You can't do that :)  You have to build the object and then add the property afterwards. (Let me look for a good duplicate question; this comes up a lot.)

Comment: I've found several questions talking about keys/values and strings but nothing getting me on the right track. Appreciate the help. I really didn't want to hardcode this for each column :)